# Postgresql - pick up field from object array to text array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

how can I pick up all id field `'{"se":[{"id":"123"}, {"id":"456"}]}'`  and get `["123", "456"]`

I tried the SQL below, but it not work, the json path always need a index.

```
select '{"se":[{"id":"123"}, {"id":"456"}]}'::JSONB   #> '{se, id}'
```

only could get the first one as text

```
select '{"se":[{"id":"123"}, {"id":"456"}]}'::JSONB   #> '{se, 0, id}'
```

Answer (score 2):

That should be done in few separate steps:

1. First take out the 'se' object
2. then expand the array items to separate json objects
3. finally find the value of the id key.
4. If you need those ids to be a list again then wrap the results with a jsonb_agg function.

```sql
SELECT
  jsonb_agg(id) id_list
FROM
  (SELECT jsonb_array_elements('{"se":[{"id":"123"}, {"id":"456"}]}'::jsonb #> '{se}') -> 'id' AS id) ids
;
```